# Obtener el indice de un elemento cuando doy click

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Tengo un problema, es que cree un `select` con varias `options`, y quiero modificar el `size` de ellos cuando de click, pero en las varias formas que e intentado siempre me deja modificar o el primero o el último, pero no me toma más elementos.

```js
// Creamos un array vacio para almacenar las iteracines
var selectores = new Array();
// Creamos un array vacio para almacenar a quien le doy click
var ElementosClick = new Array();
// Seleccionamos todos los tag select
var selector = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
// Capturamos el click y lo pasamos a una funcion
document.onclick = capturaClick;
// Iteramos y almacenamos las posiciones de los select
var i;
for (i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
    selectores[i] = onclick(selector);
    selectores.push(i);
    console.log(i);
}

console.log("Selectores: " + selectores)

function capturaClick(e) {
    // Funcion para capturar el click del raton
    var Click;
    if (e == null) {
        // Si hace click en un elemento, lo leemos
        Click = event.srcElement.tagName + asd;
        selector[i].addEventListener("click", cambioSize)
    } else {
        // Si ha hecho click sobre un destino, lo leemos
        Click = e.target.tagName + asd;
        selector[i].addEventListener("click", cambioSize)
    }
    // Añadimos el elemento al array de elementos
    ElementosClick.push(Click);
    // Una prueba con salida en consola
    console.log("Contenido sobre lo que ha hecho click: " + Click);
}

function cambioSize() {
    selector[i].size = "5";
}
```

```html
<select>
<option value="0">--Seleccionador--</option>
<option value="1">-- Uno --</option>
<option value="2">-- Dos --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que te estas complicando mucho. Para "capturar" el evento clic usa `addEventListener` usando como primer argumento `'click'` y como segundo argumento la función que quieres que se ejecute cuando ocurra el evento.

El siguiente ejemplo es muy simple. Se incluye un `select` al cual le agregamos un "listener" usando `addEventListener` según se mencionó arriba el cual registra en la consola un mensaje indicando el índice del la opción seleccionada cuando ocurrió el click.

```js
(function(){
  document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    console.info('El índice de la opción seleccionada es %s',index)
  });
})()
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Dos</option>
  <option value="3">Tres</option>
</select>
```

Nótese que se usa `querySelector` en lugar de `getElementsByTagName`. La razón de esto en este ejemplo además de una preferencia personal, es que `querySelector` devuelve el primer elemento que satisface la condición mientras que `getElementsByTagName` devuelve una colección de elementos.

Algunas alternativas para devolver un elemento en lugar de una colección son  usar `getElementById(id)`, `getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0]` entre otras.

Por otro lado, en tu código estás declarando variables globales lo cual no es del todo recomendable, particularmente si no tienes claro como manejar este ámbito y el ámbito local.

El siguiente ejemplo es un poco más completo, se incluye una sentencia `switch` para asignar el `width` según tres casos: indice 0, indice 3 y los demás. Si en verdad quieres usar el `size` que es para controlar el tamaño vertical del `select`, puedes modificarlo fácilmente en tu implementación.

```js
(function(){
  document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    switch(index){
      case 0:
        e.target.style.width = "160px";
        break;
      case 3: 
        e.target.style.width = "55px";
        break;
      default:
        e.target.style.width = "50px";  
    }
    console.info('El índice de la opción seleccionada es %s',index)
  });
})()
```

```html
<select width="160px">
  <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Dos</option>
  <option value="3">Tres</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hola ruben, muchas gracias, la implementación de ese código es excelente, me sirvió muchisimo, realmente el código es muy óptimo.

Comment: @brayan141 Gracias por tus amables palabras. Por favor, acepta la respuesta. ref. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)